# Django: reverse() and get_absolute_url() returns different output for same object?

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

When used with flatpages `reverse()` and `get_abolute_url()` returns different outputs:

```
>>> about = FlatPage.objects.get(id=2)
>>> 
>>> about
<FlatPage: /about-us/ -- About us page>
>>>
>>> about.url
>>> '/about-us/'
>>>
>>> about.get_absolute_url()
'/about-us/'
>>>
>>>
>>> reverse('django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage', args=[about.url])
'/%2Fabout-us/'    ## from where %2F comes from ?
>>>
```

Here is the sitewide `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib .flatpages import urls as flatpage_urls
# from . import blog

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include(flatpage_urls)),
]
```

Although, I am able to access to about page at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/about-us/`. From where does `%2F` come from ?

I was expecting both method should return same output. What's going on here ?

**Update:**

Here is `flatpages/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.flatpages import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<url>.*)$', views.flatpage, name='django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage'),
]
```

**Update 2:**

Updated urls.py to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # url(r'', include(flatpage_urls)),
]

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^(?P<url>.*/)$', views.flatpage),
]
```

Comment: That is odd. %2F is the url encode of '/'. It is picking up an extra slash somewhere.

Comment: What's in your `flatpage_urls`?

Comment: Did you found anything odd ? It's default, I haven't changed a bit

Comment: Actually no, don't see anything. Try setting the URI to `about-us` and add slash in the url pattern as per docs `url(r'^(?P<url>.*/)$', ...),` What does `reverse` give you now?

Comment: still getting %2F

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to insert a URL inside another URL, which just seems weird.

From your code:

```
reverse('django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage', args=[about.url])
```

You have also clarified `about.url` contains `/about-us/`. This string will get quoted and inserted in the URL:

```
http://hostname.example/<here>/
```

Or:

```
http://hostname.example/%2Fabout-us%2F/
```

I don't understand why you are not seeing the last %2F however.

Comment: If I change `url(r'', include(flatpage_urls))` to `url(r'^page', include(flatpage_urls))`, then get_absolute_url() returns `"/about-us/"` where as `reverse()` returns `"/page/about"`. Does that look right to you ? 

If that seems perfectly fine to you enlighten me. How would you go about this ?

Comment: It probably will help if you show us what the value of ``about.url`` is. Instead of us guessing.

Comment: about.url returns `/about-us/`

Comment: I don't understand why you don't always get a %2F at the start and end. However, if you want reverse to work properly every time, you need to pass the value, not the URL. ``reverse('django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage', args=['about-us'])``

Comment: I can't say I really understand this flatpage stuff however.

Comment: Don't you think using `args=['about-us']` defeats the DRY  ?

Comment: It may be that the use of the word ``url`` has been overloaded to mean different things. The ``url`` parameter within the URL is not a complete URL, that is what you are trying to generate. Sorry, don't know enough about flatpage to know the correct way of doing this.

Comment: It could be a bug in flatpage that it assumes all URLs are /

Comment: May be thats the case

Answer (score 0):

`django.contrib.flatpages` is apparently incompatibile with `reverse()` with args or kwargs. The intended use is with its custom tag:

```
{% load flatpages %}
{% get_flatpages as flatpages %}
<ul>
    {% for page in flatpages %}
        <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Source [Flatpages > Getting a list of FlatPage objects in your templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/flatpages/#getting-a-list-of-flatpage-objects-in-your-templates)

### Why the %2f

`FlatPage.get_absolute_url()` merely returns whatever is in the `self.url` field, which in your example is a string enclosed by slashes, i.e. '/about-us/'.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    # Handle script prefix manually because we bypass reverse()
    return iri_to_uri(get_script_prefix().rstrip('/') + self.url)
```

On the other hand, `reverse()` calls `_reverse_with_prefix()`, which prefixes a slash `/` to the URL, resulting in `//about-us/`. Then, it falsely determines the double-slash to mean an attempted schema rewrite, and so it replaces the second slash with the URL ASCII code `%2f` to neutralize it.

Unfortunately, the form validator for `FlatPage.url` requires that offending leading `/`:

```
def clean_url(self):
    url = self.cleaned_data['url']
    if not url.startswith('/'):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            ugettext("URL is missing a leading slash."),
            ...
```

You can sort of work around it by using a prefix without a slash, like:

```
url(r'^pages', include(django.contrib.flatpages.urls))
```

but this would also match `pagesabout-us/`. If you remove the prefix altogether like with `r'^'`, `_reverse_with_prefix()` will prefix a `/` in an attempt to avoid relative linking.

You can hard-code the URLs like the 3rd example from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/flatpages/#using-the-urlconf, but this defeats the purpose of managing URLs in the flatpages table.

```
from django.contrib.flatpages import views

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^about-us/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/about-us/'}, name='about'),
    url(r'^license/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/license/'}, name='license'),
]
```